# For find a value of obstacles height below mentioned in intermediate segment why I should take the IAF MOCA instead of FAF MOCA?

Tags: aeronautical-charts

[image][image]

It is said that we have to think all risk of flight in this segment that's why we have to take the 4420ft because the plane can be situated any point in this interval

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I fully understand your question. This may be the answer. If the Intermediate Segment does not have a published MOCA altitude, and there is no crossing altitude for the Intermediate Fix, you should stay at or above the Initial Segment MOCA. You can only descend when you are given published or explicit ATC instructions to do so.